# App crash on build (UDP socket, file already exist) - React Native

Tags: build, react-native

since 2 weeks my app crash on build and I need to clean build to get the app work.

I got this error :

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Taking device build from: /Users/menett_a/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-agnxewnospeafmevzplgrpzomptx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
Taking simulator build from: /Users/menett_a/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-agnxewnospeafmevzplgrpzomptx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
...I will output a universal build to: /Users/menett_a/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-agnxewnospeafmevzplgrpzomptx/Build/Products/Debug-universal
/* the error ===> */ mkdir: 
/Users/menett_a/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-agnxewnospeafmevzplgrpzomptx/Build/Products/Debug-universal: File exists
```

The last module I installed is crypto.